# $\sin(\theta) + \sin(5\theta) = \sin(3\theta)$ . Find number of solutions and the solutions for this equation in $[0,\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

I tried to solve the equation by doing this-

$$2\sin(\frac{\theta+5\theta}{2})\cos(\frac{\theta-5\theta}{2})=\sin(3\theta)\\
  2\sin(3\theta)\cos(2\theta) = \sin(3θ)\\
  \cos(2θ) = \frac{1}{2}\\
  1-2\sin^2(θ) = \frac{1}{2}\\
\sin^2(θ) = (\frac{1}{2})^2\\
∴ θ = nπ ± α\\
Answer = \frac{π}{6},\frac{5π}{6} $$

But in the solution there are 6 solutions and in step 3 instead of dividing $\sin(3θ)$ by $\sin(3θ)$ they have taken it as common and made "$\sin(3θ)(2\cos(2θ)-1)$"

Comment: When you divide both sides of an equation by a function of $x$ in order to "cancel" out the function, you may lose solutions, such as when the function equals $0$. Factoring is always the way to go.

Comment: You can only divide by $\sin 3\theta$ if it is not equal to zero.

Comment: Can you explain it better @Mark Bennet

Comment: No, you don't need to factor. First you note that $\sin 3\theta = 0$ is a solution and you solve for $\theta$. Then you ask, "What if $\sin 3\theta \ne 0$?" and you can now divide both sides by $\sin 3\theta$ and find more solutions.

Comment: Others have explained better in answers now. But if $a\sin 3\theta = b \sin 3\theta$ you can conclude that either $\sin 3\theta =0$ or $a=b$ (it might be possible for both to be true at the same time). Here simply putting $\theta =0$ in the original equation shows that you have missed at least one solution. You have to take both possible options to capture all the solutions to the original equation.

Comment: I compliment on a well-posed question.  You've shown you work completely and stated your question clearly and succinctly.  Good job. +1

Answer (score 2):

That's a very common mistake: if you have $ab=a$, you cannot conclude that $b=1$, unless you *know* that $a\ne0$. Indeed, you can rewrite the relation as
$$
a(b-1)=0
$$
and therefore *either* $a=0$ *or* $b=1$.

So from $2\sin3\theta\cos2\theta=\sin3\theta$ you cannot draw just $2\cos2\theta=1$: the procedure of your textbook is correct:
$$
2\sin3\theta(\cos2\theta-1)=0
$$
so
$$
\sin3\theta=0 \qquad\text{or}\qquad 2\cos2\theta-1=0
$$
Now the solutions.

From $\sin3\theta=0$ we get $3\theta=n\pi$, so $\theta=n\pi/3$ and there are four solutions in $[0,\pi]$, namely $0$, $\pi/3$, $2\pi/3$ and $\pi$.

From $\cos2\theta=1/2$ we get either $2\theta=\pi/3+2n\pi$ or $2\theta=-\pi/3+2n\pi$, hence
$$
\theta=\frac{\pi}{6}+n\pi
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\theta=-\frac{\pi}{6}+n\pi
$$
getting also the solutions $\pi/6$ and $5\pi/6$.

Answer (score 1):

As we cannot divide by $0$, there are two possible cases:

(1) $\sin3\theta=0$ (i.e. $\theta=0$, $\frac \pi3$, $\frac {2\pi}3$ or $\pi$)

Then both $2\sin3\theta\cos2\theta$ and $\sin3\theta$ are $0$. The equation is satisfied. We have $4$ solutions in this case.

(2) $\sin3\theta\ne0$.

Then we can divide both sides of $2\sin3\theta\cos2\theta=\sin3\theta$ by $\sin3\theta$ as it is not zero. So we have $\cos2\theta=\frac12$ and hence $\theta=\frac \pi6$ or $\frac{5\pi}6$. There are $2$ solutions in this case.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin3\theta=2\sin\dfrac{5\theta+\theta}2\cos\dfrac{5\theta-\theta}2$$

$$\implies\sin3\theta(2\cos2\theta-1)=0$$

If $\sin3\theta=0,3\theta=m\pi$ where $m$ is any integer

We need $0\le\dfrac{m\pi}3\le\pi\iff 0\le m\le3$

If $2\cos2\theta-1=0,\sin^2\theta=\sin^2\dfrac{\pi}6$

$\theta=n\pi\pm\dfrac{\pi}6$

We need $0\le n\pi\pm\dfrac{\pi}6\le\pi\iff0\le 6n\pm1\le6$

Taking '+' sign, $0\le 6n+1\le6\implies-1<-\dfrac16\le n\le\dfrac56<1\implies n=0$

Take '-' sign

Comment: Why did you take common of $$ sin3\theta $$ ?? You could have cancelled it also.

Comment: @somwoydipsarkar, What if $\sin3\theta=0?$